# spot fleet diversified strategy and availability zones

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to understand how tolerant a Spot Fleet with a Diversified Strategy is to an AZ failure. More specifically if I have many different instance types as part of my spot fleet, could I see all my instances running in a single AZ.

For example if my Spot Fleet included 8 types of instance types as part of it's configuration and had a target number of 4 instances. Could I see all 4 instances running in the same AZ, each with a different instance type?

I believe this could be the case as each instance type/AZ combo is seen as a separate pool, and I have not seen any indication that AZ diversity is specifically considered, just pool diversity.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If an AZ fails you could lose everything in the AZ, regardless of instance type. That's why there are multiple AZs within regions, to mitigate failures.

Comment: Right, ideally instances are spread over AZs to prevent an AZ from bringing down an entire service. The question is, will Autoscaling Spot Fleet ensure AZ diversity the way an ASG does.